# Login process through a form with no 'action' attribute?

Tags: android, html, forms, authentication, action

My problem is that i have an Android Class project and i need to develop a simple Android App to connect to my Univeristy's student info system.

There's the link for it https://my.fatih.edu.tr/

What i'm trying to do is to login here and, using regular expressions display the course info, exam date , etc. The android part is not that hard. I already started creating those expressions, and my views by using the source after i log in manually from my browser.

There's a login page at index, allows to log in through there.

When i look at the source, i see a form with attributes name and method.
No action atrribute. I searched for a script file but , couldn't find one.

I don't understand the process here.How it logs me in?
There's no action, no script files. Also no onclick atrribute on submit.

Maybe its not possible through the link but there may be other ways. I searched for it a lot on web. I see lots of examples but most of the forms has atrribute 'action'. Others use onclick.

Any idea would be great. 
Best Regards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's written on the same page in php using the method "post", which means you cannot see it. In order for you to make your application, you would need to see the full code, and the only way to do that is to contact those who made the page... =)

Comment: Well i tried this by /?username=**&password=**  but it didnt work either. 
Also i tried to contact with developers but all they say is we cannot share our sources, its top secret. You may abuse the resources we can't risk that bla bla.  
I'm gonna talk with the teacher, maybe he can do somethings.

Thanks for your reply!